# Send date to an activity.

Tags: android, android-intent

I moved Integers and also serialized object to another activity but now I'm stuck 
with move java.util.Date to my activity ,that sound like nothing but if I'll get an answer here.

It might be the first on the net.

Comment: Can you use sharedPrefs?

Comment: convert the date to string or long and sent it through extra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the current activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("date", dateObj.getTime());
startActivity(intent);
```

From next activity:

```
Date dateObj = new Date(getIntent().getExtras().getLongExtra("date", -1));
```

You should pass the time as a `long` value and convert it back on the other activity to avoid date parsing from string issues on different devices.

Comment: you can also just pass the long to the constructor and it will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

In the calle class try:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("Date",dateSelected);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

And, in the new activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==1) {
    Bundle mBundle = data.getExtras();
    String mMessage = mBundle .getString("Date");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how i ended my issue

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, EventListActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("date",date);
    startActivityForResult(i, Intent.EXTRA_DOCK_STATE_DESK);
```

and the get:

```
Date date = (Date) this.getIntent().getExtras().get("date");
```

it look like it works ,what you think about it,what is the best way?

Comment: You should pass the date as a long value and convert it back in the other activity to avoid date-parsing-from-string issues on different devices with different locales. See my answer below. :)